# Ways to access elements populated by ng-repeat from their parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Alright, to keep things simple let's say i've got some directive called `headSlides`.The directive's template is an image that is being repeated by `ng-repeat` a couple of times:

```
<img class="bg" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-src="{{image.src}}">
```

I want to access those **image elements** from within the directive's code. But when application starts and the directive's code block runs - the images aren't yet created, so you can't use something like `element.find("img")`, etc.

So, there are two workarounds that i've been using so far:

1. Use `$timeout(init,0)` inside the directive, where `init` is a function where i put all the code required to interact with images;
2. Add another directive, but this time to the images themselves and use their `load` event to emit "notification" to their parent directive (and of course add a listener to a parent for the emit event).

I believe there should be simpler, more intuitive way/ways to do this. So my question is how would you approach such task?

Comment: Your directive approach sounds good. But rather than emitting an event, how about passing in a callback function? Something like `my-on-load="loaded(image)"`

Comment: There is no "common way", since it is much more tricky than you think. Question to be answered:
- What should happen if new image is added to list/ old image is removed / image url changes?
- What should happen if one/several images fails to load?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you described, your directive looks something like this:

```
.directive('headSlides', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<img class="bg" ng-repeat="image in images track by $index" ng-src="{{image.src}}">'
    }
});
```

I would suggest trying to utilize the power of isolated scoping in your directive.

```
.directive('headSlides', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<img class="bg" ng-repeat="image in images track by $index" ng-src="{{image.src}}">',
        scope: {
            images: '=' //two way binding on the image array in your main controller
        }
    }
});
```

I don't know what init function you are using, but I tested this directive with no problems. Here is the rest of my code:

```
//My Controller    
  $scope.images = [
      {"name" : "puppy1", "src": "img/puppy1.jpg"},
      {"name" : "puppy2", "src": "img/puppy2.jpg"}
  ];

//My HTML
  <div head-slides images="images"></div>
```

Edit: For clarification, the reason this works is because the '=' in the isolated scope of the directive. Because of the two-way binding, your directive will know when the image array changes in your main controller. So in the first few ms when your js scripts are still being loaded, your images array might be seen as undefined or empty. But as soon as your image array is initialized, the directive will work and the images will display without having to use $timeout

Comment: thx for your reply, but it has little common with the asked question. It is not the matter of simply creating a directive for displaying a set of images, using isolated scopes or two-way binding... , i'd like to figure out the best way to access every `image object` from the template on the level of directive's code block... i guess i'll have to update my question to be more specific.